# Crawled properties do not show up in Search Schema in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, crawled-property, search-schema

I am running sharepoint 2019 on my windows 2019 server and it is a single computer farm.
Sharepoint seems to be installed correctly, but I am having trouble with crawled properties in Search Schema, they don't show up.

- I reindexed the crawl. Ran a full crawl, but still were not showing.
- Created a new list, added a new column with content, and then ran a full crawl again, still nothing.

Any ideas what I can look for?
Thank you.

Comment: In order to create crawled property you need to add some content as well so did you try by adding some sample record in your list?

Comment: it is already done.

Comment: Could you try to create site column and adding to List? sometime I have faced this kind of issue, and what is the type of the field?

Comment: and also validate whether list is crawled or not? you can validate it by searching some keyword related to list item from default site search or you can also validate it from Central Admin -> search service application -> crawled logs

Comment: it does not show in the crawled log.

Comment: Please check your content source and also validate whether search is not disabled in the site